# 2D Dictionary or other data structure where order of keys doesn't matter

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I want to create a data structure that can take in a pair of keys (strings) and return a value (string as well). I would like to return the same value regardless of the order in which the 2 keys are entered (e.g. data[key1][key2] returns the same value as data[key2][key1]). Is there a term/concept for this description?

My current implementation is to create a 2D dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {'key1': {'key1': None,
                    'key2': 'foo',
                    ...
                    'keyn': 'bar'},
           'key2': {'key1': 'foo',
                    'key2': None,
                    ...
                    'keyn': 'baz'},
           ...
           'keyn': {'key1': 'bar',
                    'key2': 'baz',
                    ...
                    'keyn': None}}

# Calling my_dict['key1']['key2'] and my_dict['key2']['key1'] both return 'foo', which is what I want and expect.
```

This doesn't seem right to me. I am duplicating data, and I am creating n * n entries when I only need (n * (n - 1))/2.

So, I tried creating a 1D Dictionary where the key is a tuple:

```
my_dict = {('key1', 'key2'): 'foo'}
```

But this doesn't work as calling `my_dict[('key2', 'key1')]` gives me a `KeyError`

One work-around for the 1D tuple Dictionary is to create a try/except.

```
def get_value(my_dict, key1, key2):
    try:
        return my_dict[key1][key2]
    except KeyError:
        return my_dict[key2][key1]
```

This doesn't seem intuitive and feels more like a 'band-aid' to the problem.

One method I haven't tested is a 1D Dictionary where the key uses an instance of a custom-defined class that holds `key1` and `key2` as attributes. In order to do this, the object would have to be nonmutable and hashable, where the hash function would use the object's attributes and produce the same "hash key" regardless of the order of attributes. I've never done this before and don't know how to do this. Is this the right way to go about it? I feel very stupid that I haven't been able to figure this out, as it seems like there is an easy answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the keys to compare equal regardless of order, you could use `frozensets` as keys which fits in with your idea of a custom class:

```
my_dict = {frozenset(['key1', 'key2']): 'foo'}
```

Does not matter what order you add the keys:

```
In [44]: my_dict = {frozenset(['key1', 'key2']): 'foo'}

In [45]: k = frozenset(["key1","key2"])

In [46]: k2 = frozenset(["key2","key1"])

In [47]: my_dict[k]
Out[47]: 'foo'

In [48]: my_dict[k2]
Out[48]: 'foo'
```

You can have as many values in the frozenset as you want they will still compare equal, using a frozen set is also efficient for lookups:

```
In [55]: timeit my_dict[k]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 103 ns per loop

In [56]: timeit get_value(my_dict, 'key1', 'key2')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 455 ns per loop

In [57]: timeit get_value(my_dict, 'key2', 'key1')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 455 ns per loop
```

Even timing the frozenet creation and the lookup for two elements is faster:

```
In [5]: my_dict = {frozenset(['key1', 'key2']): 'foo'}

In [6]: timeit my_dict[frozenset(["key1","key2"])]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 380 ns per loop
```

For just 3 strings you have 3! perms to check, for 6 you have 720 so for anything more than a couple checking every possible permutation is not realistic or remotely efficient.

Comment: This seems to be best solution I've found so far. Thanks for showing me `frozenset`.

Comment: @koreebay, frozensets are immutable so they can be used as dict keys, they will work if you have 1 or 101 different strings inside

Comment: Suppose the pair of keys will always come as strings. Would this still be practical if I had to create a new `frozenset` key from the two strings everytime I wanted to look up the dictionary?

Comment: @koreebay,  yes, it will work fine, if you were to have the amount of strings inside increase it would also  massively outperform trying to try every permutation, even with 3 keys you have 6 perms i.e 3!  to consider each time, for 6 strings you have 720 permutations to consider so you can see how well it scales in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) object, as you suggest. To achieve this you would need to implement `__hash__`, and `__eq__` or `__cmp__` (one of the two) methods, like so:

```
class Key:

   def __init__(self, key1, key2):
      self.key1 = key1
      self.key2 = key2

   def __hash__(self):

      # XORing two hash values is usually fine. Besides, the operation is symmetric, which is what you want
      return hash(self.key1) ^ hash(self.key2)

   def __eq__(self, other):

      if self == other:
         return True

      if self.key1 == other.key1 and self.key2 == other.key2:
         return True

      if self.key1 == other.key2 and self.key2 == other.key1:
         return True

      return False
```

Comment: Would this be the go-to method if I decided I wanted a greater number of keys (e.g. get value from 6 keys where order doesn't matter)?

Comment: Sure. You can even implement for arbitrary `N` elements. Although in that case I don't really see a gain over the suggested `frozenset` solution, so there really would be no purpose for a custom implementation. What I often do is create a type alias, such as `Key = frozenset`. Than if you need to make changes to the class later you can, not to mention that you can give more meaningful names to your objects. You'd instantiate as you usually would, such as `k = Key()`

Comment: Gotcha. So I would first need to create the new dictionary from my data, which would require me to create a `frozenset` for the pairs of keys. Then, when I want to look something up in the dictionary, I would have to create a new `frozenset` using my input keys and use that to get my value.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
my_dict = {('key1', 'key2'): 'foo'}

def get_value(my_dict, key1, key2):
    return my_dict.get((key2, key1) , my_dict.get((key1, key2)))
```

This way, you have to make less entries, and its better than `try/except`

Example

```
In [11]: my_dict = {('key1', 'key2'): 'foo'}

In [12]: def get_value(my_dict, key1, key2):
   ....:     return my_dict.get((key2, key1) , my_dict.get((key1, key2)))

In [13]: get_value(my_dict, 'key1', 'key2')
Out[13]: 'foo'
```

Comment: If you had tuples with a few elements you would manually have to check every combination

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, this returns `my_dict[(key2, key1)]` or, if it does not exist, it returns `my_dict[(key1, key2)]`.

Comment: @Delgan, yes, I missed the parens, still not very practical for more the two elements

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In this case, it is fixed that the tuple has only 2 values. I am assuming  the asker is essentially making a 2D matrix with keys instead of indexes.

Comment: @YashMehrotra,  you have n! ways to order the keys so even for 3 it is not really something you would really want to be considering, checking with an if/else would also be faster than a get

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found. The dimensions of the lists have to be the same.

```
my_dict = {}
sub_dict = {}

ks = ['key1','key2','key3','keyn']
kks = ['key1','key2','key3','keyn']
vals = [None,'foo','bar','baz']

for val in vals:    
    for kk in kks:
        sub_dict[kk] = val

print sub_dict

for k in ks:
    my_dict[k] = sub_dict

print my_dict
```

Frozenset is probably better.